# regex - only allow English(lower or upper), numbers, special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to limit user's input as followings.

1. English characters (a to z or A to Z)
2. Numeric characters ( 0 to 9 )
3. All special characters (~`!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}|;':",./<>?)

I want to prevent user to enter non-english characters (like Chinese, Korean, etc.).

```
export const isValidPasswordChar = str => {
  const regex = /^[~`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]\\{}|;':",./<>?a-zA-Z0-9]$/;
  if(regex.test(str)){
    return false
  }
  return true;
};
```

And unit test

```
it('should not allow foreign chars-1', ()=>{
    const str = '안';
    expect(isValidPasswordChar(str)).toBe(false);
  });
```

The above unit test worked before but for some reason, unit test is keep failing.  Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: You have to repeat the character class using `+` and escape the backslash ^[~`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]\\{}|;':",.\/<>?a-zA-Z0-9]+$ See https://regex101.com/r/CGxQhx/1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on right path

```
^[~`!@#$%^&*()_+=[\]\\{}|;':",.\/<>?a-zA-Z0-9-]+$
```

- You can move `-` at end so not needed to escape
- except `] and / and \` you don't need to escape other characters

```js
const isValidPasswordChar = str => {
  const regex = /^[~`!@#$%^&*()_+=[\]\{}|;':",.\/<>?a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/;
  return regex.test(str)
};

console.log(isValidPasswordChar('/'))
console.log(isValidPasswordChar('`1234567890-=;:,./'))
console.log(isValidPasswordChar('HelloPasword1234~!@#$%^&*()_+'))
console.log(isValidPasswordChar('汉字'))
```

Comment: thx.  somehow I had error that was removed after a reboot. Not sure what went wrong there. :). Anyway thx for the nice solution!